# Flutter, GeoLocator: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated

Tags: android, flutter

I am using versions geolocator: ^8.2.1.

Now when I open the Android module of the flutter project in Android studio, I get this error:

**Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly**

In the window on the bottom I get this:

**The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8
Affected Modules: geolocator_android**

Now, in my gradle.properties I removed the line 'android.enableR8=true'. but it doesn't help, because the error is coming from this module.

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I needed to update the build.gradle version:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'

This solved it.